# AWS DynamoDB Requested resource not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to connect my app to DynamoDB. I have set everything up the way Amazon recommends. But i still keep getting the same error over and over again:

```
   7-21 11:02:29.856  10027-10081/com.amazonaws.cognito.sync.demo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.amazonaws.cognito.sync.demo, PID: 10027
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: GIONOKT7E3AMTC4PO19CPLON93VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:710)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:385)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
            at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2930)
            at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:930)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1173)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:873)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:1056)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:904)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:688)
            at com.amazonaws.cognito.sync.Utils.FriendsSyncManager.initalize_credentialprovider(FriendsSyncManager.java:43)
            at com.amazonaws.cognito.sync.ValU.FriendListActivity$SyncFriends.doInBackground(FriendListActivity.java:168)
            at com.amazonaws.cognito.sync.ValU.FriendListActivity$SyncFriends.doInBackground(FriendListActivity.java:160)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: Does your table exist? What was the status of it (`CREATING` or some other state)?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Okey it seems you need to add:

```
ddbClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));  
// Add correct Region. In my case its EU_WEST_1
```

after the following line:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
```

Now it works. The table was successfully created.
Have a nice day and thanks!

Comment: Note for others who see this.  You must set the region on your Dynamo clients to the region of the table (in general this is true of all clients and their respective resources, thought most clients will default to US-EAST-1, we always recommend carefully selecting a region both for your resources and for the clients used to access them).

Comment: Your Bitcoin wallet is welcome. This is the only clue we found for the problem! Thank you

Answer (score 11):

It seems that the table you are trying to connect to doesn't exist. Verify the table name in your code agains the name of the table you created.

Please note that table name is case sensative.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check a few things:

#### Check your credentials in your code:

```
private static String awsSecretKey = "your_secret_key"; //get it in AWS web UI
private static String awsAccessKey = "your_access_key"; //get it in AWS web UI
```

#### Check your Region code and set correct value:

```
client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
```

You can get this value from your AWS Web Console. [Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/farXe.jpg)

[image]

#### Check does you have already created DynamoDB table & indexes under your Region.

If no, check your code

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Event")
public class Event implements Serializable {

    public static final String CITY_INDEX = "City-Index";
    public static final String AWAY_TEAM_INDEX = "AwayTeam-Index";
```

And create manualy from AWS Console or somehow else your table (Event in my case) and indexes (City-Index, AwayTeam-Index in my case). Please note - table and index name in case sensative.

Good sample - https://github.com/aws-samples/lambda-java8-dynamodb

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html) it's either you don't have a Table with that name or it is in CREATING status.

I would double check to verify that the table does in fact exist, in the correct region, and **you're using an access key that can reach it**.

Or you might select the wrong **region**.

Answer (score 0):

Along with @Yuliia Ashomok's answer

AWS C++ SDK 1.7.25

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
clientConfig.region = Aws::Region::US_WEST_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Spring boot, you can configure the region via application properties:

in src/main/resources/application.yaml

```
cloud:
  aws:
    region:
      static: eu-west-1
```

Answer (score 0):

As this problem is some what platform agnostic.  For anyone coming at the same problem from .NET/C# ...

You can instantiate your client with the Endpoint in the constructor:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1 );
```

I would have assumed that this would have been brought in from you AWS Profile but seems not although you could do something like this, where profile is imported from your SharedCredentialsFile:

```
new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, profile.Region );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have already created the table in DynamoDB but still getting this error. That means you may chances that your region is not correct. Just look at the top right corner of your AWS portal, with your profile dropdown. One another dropdown will give you the option to select your region. And now follow the process again with the right region.

Hope this works. This works for me.

Comment: Hello...
Inspect // Watch ...
Your answer, in addition to being considered a comment. It is poorly done.
It is useful to insert an effective response, with codes and references. Concluding a practical and efficient solution.
This platform is not just any forum. We are the largest help and support center for other programmers and developers in the world. Review the terms of the community and learn how to post.